# My drive shows less space than I should have, because of hidden or encrypted files

Tags: windows, hard-drive

My drive has 92GB used space, 95GB free out of a 220GB partition. There are 33GB in the air I can't find.

I already did a cleanup, emptied the recycle bin, history and temporary files too. I believe that it's possibly space my brother occupies with a program he uses to hide (possibly encrypted) files.

I don't know the name, I've just seen him do it on USB and PC, and they don't appear visible or hidden. The result is what you read above. Is there any way of finding those files to delete them, or could it be something else?

I already tried FreeCommander too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [WinDirStat](http://windirstat.info/) and find where the data is on the drives, assuming they are all partitioned to take up 100% of the disk.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the operating system, this could be shadow copies of the disk, which Microsoft uses to save "restore points".  Here's an explaination of [Vista's system restore](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-vista/What-is-System-Restore).  Shadow copies don't show up as files in windows explorer.

Comment: thank you also wasnt the problem but checked just in case and now i have even more free space on my disk very helpfull info